# How can I get Monero anonymously with Bitcoin or Etherium?

Tags: monerod

I want to get Monero, but not through my usual crypto exchange. What is the best place to get it without doing KYC? Preferably low fees and quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Use a no signup, no KYC exchange. I think the one most people use is xchange.cx

Cheap and fast way to get Monero from any crypto.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick answer!! I did it with xchange.cx and got the XMR in 10 minutes.